# specify the version to run when using node command

Tags: node.js

I have a node js command and I run it in a .bat file in my mac.

```
node "%thisPath:~0,-1%\test-update.js" %PUB_ALIAS% && (exit) || (pause)
```

everything looks good.
I need to specify the version of node I want to address when I call the node command. Something like this:

```
node --v 10 "%thisPath:~0,-1%\test-update.js" %PUB_ALIAS% && (exit) || (pause)
```

But I cannot see any option in the node --help command for that.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node binary does not provide this feature out of the box.
If you need to run multiple node versions on windows then you will need a node version manager, eg: [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) or [nodist](https://github.com/nullivex/nodist) so you will be able to do something like `nvm use v10` and issue your command on the next line of your script.